# SimpleMembershipProvider in MVC4 throws NotSupportedException on methods when initialized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am using the built-in SimpleMembership of the ASP.net MVC4 template and want to create an admin panel to reset passwords and similar operations on the user base.

I am using SecurityGuard.MVC4 nuget as starting point and am getting NotSupportedException on most actions. SecurityGuard uses the Membership property of the controller to call methods such as GetAllUsers(), GetUser() and ResetPassword() on SimpleMembershipProvider and they all throw NotSupportedException. From documentation it seems that this is by design:

[SimpleMembershipProvider.GetAllUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.getallusers%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

> Note: If the SimpleMembershipProvider class has been initialized using
>   a call to the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection() method, this
>   method is not supported and will throw a NotSupportedException
>   exception. However, if the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()
>   method has not been called, and if you have configured your site to
>   use the standard ASP.NET membership provider, this method is passed
>   through to the standard membership provider.

What am I missing? It seems I need to choose between using WebSecurity for standard stuff like WebSecurity.CreateUser() and to use the provider directly?

I can work around this, but I am primarily confused on why I can't get both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SimpleMembership` is deliberately designed to be.. well, Simple.  `WebSecurity` uses `SimpleMembership`, and uses the `ExtendedMembershipProvider` class that `SimpleMembership` is derived from.

Essentially, SimpleMembership does not implement any functions that are not present in WebSecurity, and GetAllUsers is one of those.  Yes, this is by design.

You have several options.  All of them are workarounds.

1. You can simply do your own query to get all users.
2. You can create your own Membership provider derived from SimpleMembership and implement those functions
3. You can go back to the SqlMembershipProvider (or Universal Providers) (but eschew WebSecurity)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for the options to work around it. I will probably derive my own membership provider. Just concerned that rolling my own will introduce security issues.

Comment: I took a closer look to the decompiled code and documentation of SimpleMembershipProvider and found that if not initialized it will fall back to using the PreviousProvider property. This is basically any provider passed into its constructor, not sure how that works when defined in Web.Config as the default provider. Either way, SimpleMP does not implement any of this stuff, it just falls back to the "previous" provider if it is not initialized itself and with no fall back has no other option than to throw NotSupportedException. I guess it was this fallback that confused me in the first place.

Comment: @AndreasLarsen - If you don't initialize SimpleMembership, then you can't use WebSecurity with it.  It will throw an exception.  SimpleMembership does not get configured in Web.Config, but rather is configured through an attribute placed on the AccountController.  This overrides the membership defined in web.config, so if you don't init SimpleMembership, it uses whatever is configured in web.config.

Comment: But the MVC4 boilerplate already defines this in web.config, such as <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">. I thought this was just to decide what instance is set in Membership.Provider property of controllers. Are you saying you can use WebSecurity without having any default providers defined in web.config or are you just saying that initialization is required?

Comment: @AndreasLarsen - No.  The default MVC4 doesn't include any membership sections in the Web.Config.

Comment: You are right, I just double-checked. I must have added them at some point thinking it was necessary.