# Method Membership.GetAllUsers() is not working in SimpleMembership with web form

Tags: asp.net

I am using `Membership.GetAllUsers()` method in `SimpleMemebership` for getting all user but it is not working .It throws following error "**Specified method is not supported**".

Comment: Do you have a stack trace, at least?

Comment: correct asnwer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12708283/1348121

Answer (score 2):

***Membership.GetAllUsers()*** will not work with **SimpleMembership**, If the **SimpleMembershipProvider** class has been initialized using a call to the ***WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()*** method, this method is not supported and will throw a **NotSupportedException** exception.
You can see it on following [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.getallusers%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

The alternative way to get all User in **SimpleMemberShip** is

```
dynamic users;
using (var db = WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open("UserDb"))
 {
   users = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Users");
 }
```

here **UserDb** is my Demo Connectionstring name. You can see this code in following [Page](http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp-net-webpages/).

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819183/simplemembershipprovider-in-mvc4-throws-notsupportedexception-on-methods-when-in) Membership.GetAllUsers() is not supported by SimpleMembership.